# What exactly is setoid hell?

Tags: lean, coq, quotient

One of the only arguments I've heard about why Lean is better than Coq is that you can construct quotients of built-in structures by default. (In Coq, you apparently have to use Setoids instead of Sets, or so I've heard, hence the title).

However, I am still having a hard time seeing why this supposed problem is actually such a problem.

Could someone elaborate on this for me?

I would like to see some sort of minimal working example, where a theorem with a nice short proof in Lean has a much more verbose, less elegant proof in Coq.

---

Edit: I'm grateful this question sparked a bunch of really interesting discussion, the main reason I have not accepted an answer is because none of them have satistifed:

> I would like to see some sort of minimal working example

Comment: I found this fascinating issue which talks about _why_ Coq doesn't support quotients, but it does not address my question: https://github.com/coq/coq/issues/10871

Comment: Small nitpick:  I wouldn't say that setoid hell is the *only* difference between Lean and Coq that would lead some users to choose one over the other.  There are also differences of user experience and culture ([here](https://artagnon.com/articles/leancoq) and [here](https://proofassistants.stackexchange.com/questions/153/what-are-the-main-differences-between-coq-and-lean)).  (Lean 4 will also be a full programming language, which may interest some users and but not others.)

Comment: I am starting to be a bit annoyed by this rumour, but let me restate the truth here: **the fact that Coq cannot have Lean-style quotients is pure FUD**. You can definitely add them via private inductive types and axiomatize the rest in SProp. Obviously you get as a result the same kind of issues. The only real argument is that Coq libraries do not rely on this structure since it's not part of the stdlib, so you're bound to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: @Pierre-MariePédrot Totally agree!  And in the HoTT library we do [exactly that](https://github.com/HoTT/HoTT/blob/master/theories/Colimits/Quotient.v), minus the SProp.

Comment: @Pierre-MariePédrot so the only difference is actually that Lean decided to include this in the standard library by default, but Coq didn't and so you have to build it yourself?

Comment: @setholopolus Yes. Don't get me wrong, this is a very important difference, because that means everybody relies on the same definition in Lean. This gives more code sharing and an easier time for people that do not understand how to reimplement them.

Comment: This rumour was started by an ignorant comment I made in my 2019 MS talk that will not die and which I have repeatedly apologised for. However one thing I am unclear on is whether trickery in Coq can make the commutativity of the diagram coming from quotient.lift be definitionally true (lift f (quotient.mk x) = f x := rfl). I should say that I do not place too much weight on definitional equality any more, so am not sure of the importance of this question, but I don't know the answer to it anyway.

Comment: @Pierre-MariePédrot  Kevin brings up a good point.  Whether or not it is actually useful, can the Lean-like quotients you are alluding to in Coq have the definitional equality property Kevin is asking about, or does that have to be built in like in Lean's quotients?

Comment: Yes, they will enjoy this equation definitionally.

Comment: About your edit: the reason there are no minimal examples is that weve concluded (in the comments and answers) that the premise of your question was false. It's true it would be interesting to see concrete examples of approaches to quotients/coherences in different proof assistants, but this would be better off as an entirely different question.

Answer (score 18):

Setoid hell means that you are doing by hand the work of a compiler.

A setoid is just a type equipped with an equivalence relation. One can then define functions between setoids as functions between the underlying types respecting the equivalence. Similarly, you can endow other type formers with a setoid structure. Long story short, this construction constitutes a [syntactic model of TTobs](https://hal.inria.fr/hal-02281225/document), a type theory with [many nice properties](https://hal.inria.fr/hal-03367052/document). TTobs contains MLTT and also features quotient types, so working from within it allows to define stuff in the standard mathematical way.

Now, such a syntactic model can be seen as a compilation from TTobs into (some variant of) Coq. Like any compilation process, it is both systematic *and* tedious. Everytime the user writes a function, for instance, she has to provide a proof of respectfulness *by hand*, when it should actually be inferable. In addition to being annoying it is also error-prone when done manually.

This is not as tedious as writing the X86 assembly code corresponding to the compilation of a Coq program after extraction and OCaml compilation, but it is still a PITA. Who would do it knowing it can be done by a computer faster, in a safer way and with a high-level abstraction as a bonus?

Comment: I wonder given the OP’s request for a practical example and your comment where your feel the situation is poorly understood, that your answer could be improved by two or three examples: (1) A Coq proof going through setoid hell.  (2) (If you wish) a Lean proof of the same thing avoiding setoid hell.  (3) A Coq proof avoiding setoid hell similar to Lean, by using private inductive types.

Comment: I don't think the addresses the problem apart from repeating what the OP probably already knows. If it is systematic, why can't tactics work? It's these questions that is the crux.

Comment: There is no simple example, because it's a matter of scalability. You don't appreciate scalability until you hit large-ish examples. (Said otherwise, tediousness is not an objective criterion.)

Comment: Can you explain some of the abbreviations in your posts (TTobs, MLTT, FUD)?

Comment: @Pierre-MariePédrot is there really no way you can give a small example of something that you need quotients to prove? Can you at least give examples of what types of theorems that you would want to have quotients in order to prove? I appreciate the elaboration here, but I'm still lost on why people want quotients so badly in the first place.

Comment: Many constructions in algebra are natural with quotients, such as [tensor products of modules](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor_product_of_modules). Any construction can be simulated without quotients, but you have to carry around the equivalence relation somewhere. If a language makes this bookkeeping easy then perhaps it doesn't matter, but from experience of developing mathematics most seem to agree that the Setoid approach does not make it convenient to carry the equivalence relation data around. Quotients are the ideal because the constructed type automatically satisfies the relation.

Comment: @setholopolus As for abbreviations: A link is provided for TTobs, MLTT=Martin-Löf Type Theory, PITA=Pain in the a**, FUD=Fear-uncertainty-doubt (Pierre-Marie means [perhaps hyperbolically] that there is a big misunderstanding [negative PR campaign?] about this situation and that in fact Coq does support Lean-style quotients although they are not in the standard library). Last (if you missed it) Andrew just answered your question about why one wants quotients.

Comment: @setholopolus, I think that Universal Algebra is a good example of setoid hell: in ordinary mathematics your structures are sets with the corresponding operations; in TT you ask the structures to be setoids (instead of mere types) and the operations to respect the equality. Then you have homomorphism and want to talk about two of them being equal, so you need also a setoid (equality being extensional equality) for them. Things get uglier when you leave a monosort setting.

Comment: I would add: I'm not sure it's possible to appreciate how bad things get without examples involving _families_ of types (indexed by setoids). I've seen people claim that working with setoids is not so bad, but the corresponding examples usually end up being those where we have _simple_ types replaced by setoids. I think families of setoids indexed by setoids are also where you would start seeing gaps in what tactics are able to help with (because even defining what a family _is_ is complicated, despite being completely rote).

Answer (score 13):

*Disclaimer:* I know very little about Lean, so I would be happy to be proved wrong.

There is no escape from setoid hell. Lean simply gives a different way of doing the same thing one does in Coq.

In Lean, given a type $X$ with a relation $\sim$, we obtain a new type $\tilde X = X/\sim$ such that if $x\sim y$ then $[x] = [y]$. In Coq, $\tilde X$ is not allowed to be a type because we can no longer decide whether two elements of $\tilde X$ are equal (there is a way around this if your relation is decidable, say using [SSReflect](https://coq.inria.fr/refman/proof-engine/ssreflect-proof-language.html), and Lean probably has similar functionality).

In Lean, if you want to define a function $f : \tilde X\to Y$ (or a proposition on $\tilde X$), you need to use `quot.lift` which requires you to prove that whenever $x \sim y$ then $f([x]) = f([y])$. In Coq, you simply define a function $f : X\to Y$, then prove a congruence lemma `f_eq` saying that $x\sim y$ implies $f(x) = f(y)$.

Now the difference is that in Lean, given $x\sim y$ and $f : \tilde X\to Y$, you can rewrite  $f([x])$ to $f([y])$ automatically using elimination for equality, whereas in Coq, you have to invoke the congruence lemma `f_eq`.

So in summary, Lean keeps track of the congruence rule in the definition of $f$, whereas in Coq you have to keep track of $f$ and `f_eq`.

I don't actually know exactly what setoid hell refers to, but if it refers to keeping track of congruence rules within the term then I suppose you could say Lean avoids this, but the amount of work you need to do is the same.

I am nethertheless going to quote [Jacques Carette](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65509179/1888743)

> Setoid hell arises not because some coherences must be proven. It arises when you're forced to prove these coherences again and again when defining functions that can't possibly "go wrong". So Setoid hell is actually caused by a failure to provide proper abstraction mechanisms.

---

As Jason Rute points out, this means that in Coq, if we want to prove nested equalities of the form $f(g(x)) = f(g(y))$ given $x\sim y$, we would need to first apply `g_eq`, then apply `f_eq`, which can be cumbersome. However, Coq supports [generalized rewriting](https://coq.inria.fr/refman/addendum/generalized-rewriting.html), where $f$ and $g$ can be declared as `Parametric Morphism`'s (given $\sim$ is declared a `Parametric Relation`) which allows directly rewriting in this setting.

Comment: Does your analysis change much for functions $f,g:\tilde{X}\to \tilde{X}$?  In this latter case, if $f(x)$ is buried in, say $g(f(x))$, with quotients you can simply rewrite (or maybe even defeq in some cases) to show $g(f([[x]]))=g(f([[y]]))$.  But for setoids, you would need to apply congruence rules for both $f$ and $g$, to get $g(f(x))\sim g(f(y))$ and you would have to do it at every step of a possibly long set of equivalences, right?  Of course, that doesn’t preclude the possibility of having good automation or abstraction mechanisms to do this for you as mention by others.

Comment: I guess I’m suggesting by lifting equivalence to equality, it seems you can avoid a large amount of bookkeeping in situations like this since equality already has good tooling via rewriting, simplification, and definitional equality.  With quotients it seems you only need congruence when going from $X$ to $\tilde{X}$.  But for setoids, you need it for any time you work with functions on $\tilde{X}$.

Comment: @JasonRute Thanks for pointing this out! See my edit.

Comment: @JasonRute It's worth pointing out that Lean [breaks definitional equality](https://github.com/coq/coq/issues/10871#issuecomment-541325340) because of this.

Comment: I think it’s also worth pointing out that for Lean users that example isn’t a big deal at all (as the rest of that discussion you linked to shows).  And to avoid any misconceptions, let me also remark that Lean is proven to be consistent.

Comment: @JasonRute I'm not trying to antagonize. Lean is IMO better suited for math and I have nothing against that.

Comment: I totally understand.  It was just that this particular example has a tendency to be misunderstood, so I wanted to add a clarification, but your point is an accurate one that also should be brought up.  (Also good answer to the question.)

Comment: Hot damn, I said something quotable!

Answer (score 6):

The main difference between setoids and quotients occurs when defining new functions in terms of existing functions, such as `f(x) = g(h(x))`. With setoids you will need to prove a lemma that `f` respects the equivalence relation using a trivial proof with the lemmas that `g` and `h` respect the equivalence relation. Coq has the `solve_proper` tactic to solve such trivial goals, but you still need to state the lemma and invoke this tactic.

With quotients, you do not need to do that: if `g` and `h` operate on the quotient type, then `f` also operates on the quotient type, which means that `f` automatically respects the equivalence relation by type checking. With quotients, you only need to prove a lemma when you define a function by actually opening up the quotient and peeking at a representative.